# Static html to wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress

I have a static HTML site (about ten years old) which I am going to migrate to a Wordpress site.

I have used Wordpress before but never as a migration target. From some initial background reading I have come up with the following process to perform the migration:

1. Check hosting provider/package for Wordpress suitability
2. Generate complete current site map
3. Make a complete backup of current site
4. Install Wordpress in subdirectory
5. Install Maintenance mode plugin and activate
6. Migrate content to Wordpress instance (looks like this could be
   painstaking..)
7. Install suitable theme
8. Customise selected theme with Logo/fonts/colours etc.
9. Deactivate maintenance mode
10. Make Wordpress site available from domain root
11. Delete old static html site files

(The migration may take place over several weeks/months so I need the static HTML site to be available until step 10 is completed)

In my naivety are there any pitfalls in the above process, or additional issues I have failed to consider?

Are there any other accepted 'best practices' when performing this kind of migration?

Comment: Depending (a lot) on your content, the migration may be much easier than you anticipate. I wouldn't 'launch' WordPress in the same space just yet, unless you need to. Are you unable to manage your hosts/virtual hosts/server configuration?

Comment: Thanks - what are the main reasons to avoid installing WordPress in the same space?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-wordpress-theme-from-static-html-creating-template-files--wp-33939

For developers who want the theme converted from HTML in easy way (but no guarantee if it can produce the output as expected):

http://www.htmltowordpressconverter.com/

Hope this was helpful!!!!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress theme styles come in all shapes and sizes. Converting from a static HTML site to something database driven like WordPress can be as easy or complicated as you want.

If you just want to integrate WordPress into an existing HTML theme it's as easy as installing WP, setup the database and config, then building in the old HTML structure using WP. This way everything will be the same but managed within WordPress i.e. Pages, Menus, Sidebars.

Here's are some useful links:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

And here's a "Start from Scratch" theme that would be simple to start from. Just install it, activate it, then begin migrating the main content i.e. copy and images etc, and building the theme itself.

http://adopttheweb.com/start-from-scratch.zip